# Convert extracted string to Tabular cells

Tags: python, pdfminer

I have extracted from a pdf using pdfminer and I received textual data from it.

```
1. Seema visited a Natural Gas Compressing Unit and found that the gas can
be liquefied under specific conditions of temperature and pressure. While
sharing her experience with friends she got confused. Help her to identity
the correct set of conditions.
(a) Low temperature, low pressure
(b) High temperature, low pressure
(c) Low temperature, high pressure
(d) High temperature, high pressure

(1)

2. Which of the following are physical changes?

(i) Melting of iron metal
(ii) Rusting of iron
(iii) Bending of an iron rod
(iv) Drawing a wire of iron metal
(a) (i), (ii) and (iii)
(b) (i), (ii) and (iv)
(c) (i), (iii) and (iv)
(d) (ii), (iii) and (iv)

3. Which one of the following has maximum number of atoms?

(a) 18 g of H2O
(b) 18 g of O2
(c) 18 g of CO2
(d) 18 g of CH4
```

I want to convert the extracted text to add to a list.
Basically I want to make a list of questions with their options from the pdf. So question 1 being first element, question 2 is second and so on...

Comment: Actually this is a single, complete string. I want to divide it in parts and store as elements of list.